# UIView shadow too defined

Tags: ios, swift, shadow

I am trying to make a shadow on a UIView like so

[image]

This is what I ended up with. I combined what Invision gave me

```
let layer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 454, width: 359, height: 100))
layer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
layer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.08).cgColor
layer.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
layer.layer.shadowRadius = 4
self.view.addSubview(layer)
```

And some other code I found browsing StackOverflow to get to this

```
Layer.ShadowRadius = 2.0f;
Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 0.08f).CGColor;
Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(2, 2);
Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.80f;
Layer.ShadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(Layer.Bounds).CGPath;
Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
```

[image]

As you can see my shadow is a lot more defined then the one in invision and I am having trouble figuring out why without spending hours guessing and checking. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Lighter color, bigger radius, slightly more y offset.

Comment: Also use a color with full opacity and set the `shadowOpacity` value in the layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get a shadow without adding a background color to the view. Anyhow, here's the settings I tried and the result:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 454, width: 359, height: 100))
view.backgroundColor = .white
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
view.layer.shadowRadius = 5

self.view.addSubview(view)
```

[image: Result]

So here are the settings for you to consider:

- Use a solid color for `shadowColor`
- Adjust the lightness via `shadowOpacity`
- Control the "hardness" via `shadowRadius`. The smaller the radius, the harder or more defined the shadow is.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend to use a brighter color. In your case it seems to be very dark. Furthermore increasing the radius could lead to a less defined shadow as it will obviously be spread over a bigger area.

To brighten the color just increase all three rgb values here. If you want a very light shadow I would recommend setting the rgb channels to somewhat around 200. (255 produces white)

```
layer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.08).cgColor
```

You can increase the radius here.

```
layer.layer.shadowRadius = 4
```

Comment: Hey, you should propose to what values OP should change the properties.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I would recommend just playing around with those values because everyones preferences are different. Even though setting the rgb channels to around 180-200 would be a good start. This will produce a very light shadow.

Comment: Then put exactly that recommendation into your answer.